# Java read image from 2 directories up

Tags: java, file, png, directory

How can I place an image on screen that is 2 directories up? Here's my code:

```
package mousemaze;

// Imports
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LoadScreen extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String logoPath = "././images/snakyboLogo.png";
    BufferedImage logoImage;
    JLabel logoLabel;

    public LoadScreen() {
        try {
            System.out.println(logoPath);
            logoImage = ImageIO.read(new File(logoPath));
            System.out.println("1");
            logoLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(logoImage));
            System.out.println("2");
            add(logoLabel);
            System.out.println("End");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Fail");
        }
    }
}
```

But it fails at

```
logoImage = ImageIO.read(new File(logoPath));
```

So I think it can't find the specified file on in that directory.
My folder structure is:

- src\mousemaze\LoadScreen.java
- src\images\snakyboLogo.png

So i'm guessing that this isn't how I specify a file in an entirely different package, so how do I do this?

Comment: Whats the point of specifying `./.`? That just resolves to the current directory. In any case 1) Don't use relative paths when loading files 2) Use a resource stream instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Problem 1 - The path literal `.` resolves to the current directory, I assume you meant to use `..`.
- Problem 2 - Its never advisable to read from a file in Java using relative paths. If ever your application is deployed in anything but your assumed structure, it will break

You will get more mileage from using a resource stream

```
InputStream logoStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/snakyboLogo.png");
if(logoStream != null) logoImage = ImageIO.read(logoStream);
```

Comment: Isn't if(imageStream != null) supposed to be if(logoStream != null)? It error's if I put imageStream.

Comment: @Snakybo - indeed it is, thanks for pointing that out. Updated.

Comment: And it always returns null, do I place it inside the try statement? try {
    InputStream logoStream  = getClass().getResourceAsStream("snakyboLogo.png");
    System.out.println(logoStream);
    if(logoStream != null) {
        logoImage = ImageIO.read(logoStream);
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
}

Comment: @Snakybo - part of the path was missing, I've updated my answer.

Comment: It still returns null, no matter where I put the image or how I type .getResourceAsStream("/images/snakyboLogo.png");

Comment: Odd, it works for me, see screenshot [here](http://tinyurl.com/a77quay). How are you running the program, and what is your classpath?

Comment: Oh derp, I found the error. I filtered the images/ folder out becouse I don't want it show in the package explorer, but I didn't realise it ignores it when building the project. Derp